# jQuery: how to navigate a table row to extract cell data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to navigate a table row that has been clicked, to extract data from other parts of the row.

this is the HTML snippet of the row that was clicked on:

```
<tr><td class=" sorting_1">Foobar</td>
    <td>Hello</td><td><a href="/some/path/abc.html">42</a></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><img src="/images/img.gif"></td>
    <td>7:44 AM</td>
    <td><ul><li><a href="/path2/read/3">Read it</a></li>
            <li><a class="booboo" href="#">Just do it</a></li>
        </ul></td>
```

The cell element that was clicked on has class "booboo".

I want to be able to select the following data:

- the id used in the url of the previous li a sibling (it is 3 in the example given above)
- the name in the first column (it is 'Foobar' in the example given)
- the url of the anchor elem in the 2nd cell (should be /some/path/abc.html in this example)

Can anyone point out the functions required to navigate a table row, preferably with a snippet showing how to select the values in the sample snippet shown above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No hill for a climber](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)...

```
$("table a.booboo").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tr = $this.closest("tr"); 

    // the id used in the url of the previous li a sibling
    var a = $this.closest("ul").find("li:first a").attr("href");
    a = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    alert(a);

    // the name in the first column
    var b = tr.find("td:first").text();
    alert(b);

    // the url of the anchor elem in the 2nd cell
    var c = tr.find("td:eq(2) a").attr("href");
    alert(c);
});
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QMnXp/)

Comment: thanks very much for the commented code. This will hel0p me understand better.

Comment: Would this not be the 3rd cell if indexs start at 0?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want the various methods in the ["traversing" section](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) of the docs, in particular:

- `parent` to go from the `a` that was clicked to the `li` it's in.
- `prev` to go from the `li` to the previous `li`.
- <s>`parents` (probably `.parents("tr:first")`) to get to the row itself.</s> *Gah!* As [Josh points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068303/jquery-how-to-navigate-a-table-row-to-extact-cell-data/5068410#5068410), I meant `closest`. (And I *use* `closest`. And yet...)
- `find` to find elements within the row (e.g., `row.find("td:first").text()` to get the text of the first cell)

...as well as [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), possibly, to get the `href` attribute value.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding all the related data as attributes of your `a.booboo` when you generate the table?

```
<a class="booboo"
   data-id="3"
   data-name="Foobar"
   data-url="/some/path/abc.html">Just do it</a>
```

Then you can retrieve the data like this:

```
$('a.booboo').click(function() {
  var user = $(this).data()
  alert(user.id)
})
```

I think it's a better solution because it doesn't depend on the exact structure of your HTML code and it's cleaner than the other solutions proposed.

Comment: Because changing the server-side code that generates the markup might not be an option...

Comment: @Josh so what? It's still a better approach when changing server-side code **is** an option. Like, in 99% of the cases.

Comment: I agree it's a more ideal solution, but in my experience when a front-end developer wants a server-side change made, it slows things down (because server-side changes require a whole different kind of testing and unless you are working in a little company, somebody else will be making that change and you'll have to wait for them).  Plus... with your solution, you are duplicating data that is already available just to make your Javascript easier to code.  Since when was that "better"?

Comment: @Josh, I agree on your first point, but I disagree on the second one. The point is not to make it easier for me to code, but to make it more maintainable. I don't want to rewrite the code every time somebody changes HTML a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If the html structure is fixed, you can use this:

```
$(".booboo").click(function(){
  var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var foobar = tr.cells[0].innerHTML;
  var url = tr.cells[2].firstChild.href;
  var id = this.parentNode.previousSibling.firstChild.href.match(/\d+$/)[0];
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".booboo").click(function() {

  var a = $(this);
  var tr = a.closest("tr");

  var readItUrl = a.closest("li").prev().find("a").attr("href");
  var tdText = tr.find("td:first").text();
  var tr.find("td:eq(1) > a").attr("href");

});
```